# Can you use Interrupted Time Series analysis across 4 weeks, with 12 time points?

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

We have had some collaborators suggest interrupted time series analysis as a method for analysing some observational data, that investigated the effect of an intervention on an observed outcome (lunch bought or brought from home). However, we only have a 2 week baseline (observations occurring on 2 days for the first week, and 3 days for the second), and a 2 week intervention period (with 3 days per week of observations).

Will this be sufficient for this kind of analysis? All the examples I've seen have been population level observations across a much larger time period.

Comment: Do you have a control group to compare against?

Comment: @forecaster Yes, we have two conditions (one experimental, one active control) that we're trying to compare

Comment: If that is the case, then you should be able use that as independent variable and control for confounding trends and trends. 12 data points is still short.